# Transform web text in Spanish to ASCII

Tags: r, utf-8, web-scraping, ascii, text-mining

I'm using R to do text mining. I have downloaded html files. I have issues trying to convert to text because the language is Spanish.
I used:

```
text<-readLines(i,encoding="UTF-8")
```

But still, I could have text like:

> prueba= "hizo la diagonal desde la izquierda hacia el centro  y
>   combinÃ³ con Ãngel Di MarÃ­a, quien despachÃ³ el centro desd e la
>   derecha con el revÃ©s de la zurda para que Sergio AgÃ¼ero  empujara en
>   la entrada del Ã¡rea chica."

Where combinÃ³=combinó, Ã¡rea=área, etc. I need to keep only the original alphabetic characters.
I could have another text like the following:

> prueba2="El club Atlas, de la Primera D, estÃ¡ en la
>   constante bÃºsqueda de crecimiento. Y en esa
>   bÃºsqueda, consiguiÃ³ un aliado de lujo. El
>   presidente Maxi Ambrosio viajÃ³ al Vaticano y tras
>   entregarle una camiseta al Papa, le pidiÃ³ al propio
>   Francisco que adopte a los de General RodrÃ­guez como su
>   segundo equipo, despuÃ©s de San Lorenzo. La
>   reacciÃ³n fue positiva"

where, for example, "despuÃ©s" means "después"

I tried:

```
iconv(prueba,to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
```

But I get the same text.

How can I transform the text to ASCII?

Comment: what is the encoding in your `options()`? what happens when you do `Encoding(text) <- 'UTF-8'; print(text)`

Comment: @rawr, hi. I get the same. and in options I have UTF-8. Encoding(prueba2) <- 'UTF-8'; print(prueba2)
[1] "El club Atlas, de la Primera D, est&Atilde;&iexcl; en la\nconstante b&Atilde;&ordm;squeda de crecimiento.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct input encoding? The fact that you are getting funny symbols when setting encoding="UTF-8" leads me to believe it is not, in fact, UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @MrFlick, the originating software was configured to save UTF-8. Assuming the possibility that it didn't --- would it be possible, knowing specific cases of non-ASCII characters in the text and how they should look, to figure out the actual encoding it is in?

Comment: You could do some detective work to figure out what bytes are in the file and then look at each possible code page to see where the expected symbol corresponds to the byte sequence you observer. But you'll want to do that before R does any encoding conversion because then things get much more tricky; loot at the raw bytes. The HTML files may have encoding information in the header.